# Gulp-Angular + TypeScript + Visual Studio Debugging

Tags: angular, visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2013, gulp

I have used [Gulp-Angular](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular) yomen generator to scaffold an application with TypeScript. I want to debug typescript in visual studio but also want to keep the gulp tasks from Gulp-Angular as is.

I disabled "Build On Save" feature in visual studio so it no longer builds the .ts files. And there were additional suggestions [here](https://github.com/ivogabe/gulp-typescript/issues/65) to keep visual studio away from the type script files.

Afterwards I launched the application by executing 'gulp serve' task and then attached the visual studio to iexplorer.exe - script process. But the typescript break points in visual studio are not getting hit.

I also inspected the final minified JS file and it has the source map as base64 encoded string inline and not as a path to a separate .map file.

Please suggest a way to make the typescript debugging work in Visual Studio.